# openscad drill into group created by for

Tags: openscad

I know that when I use for it creates a group of the generated children.
I created a module called grid like so:

```
module grid(x0,y0,dx,dy,nx,ny) {
    for (x=[0:1:nx-1]) {
        for(y=[0:1:ny-1]) {
            i=x*nx+y;
            echo(i);
            translate([x0+x*dx,y0+y*dy,0]) children(i);
        }
    }
}
```

which when used like this:

```
grid(-50,-50,25,25,5,5) {
    cube([10,10,10],center=true);
    cube([10,10,10],center=true);
    cube([10,10,10],center=true);    
    cube([10,10,10],center=true);
    //.. continue to create 25 cubes total    
}
```

arranges the cubes in a nice grid.

however my original hope and intention was to use it like this:

```
grid(-50,-50,25,25,5,5) {
    for(i=[0:1:24]) {
        cube([10,10,10],center=true);
    } 
}
```

Which fails because the for operator returns a group and not a set of children.

Why does the for add a group to begin with? (also leading to the need for *intersection_for*)

And is there a way for my Grid operator module to handle the children of the group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally hope for the grouping/union for elements within a for() to become optional at some time.

If you don't mind compiling OpenSCAD from source, you could try it already today.
There is an ongoing issue [Lazy union (aka. no implicit union)](https://github.com/openscad/openscad/issues/350)
and a patch here [Make for() UNION optional](https://github.com/nrdvana/openscad/commit/c15a0827939896d02067c339bb962468f074aa9e)

Comment: At least for Ubuntu users, compiling from source is no longer needed. Ubuntu 20.04 has the development version OpenSCAD 2020.09.18, where the experimental feature "lazy-unions" can be enabled in the preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Just updated my knowledge of OpenSCAD, there is a better solution:

```
module nice_cube()
{
    translate([0,0,$height/2]) cube([9,9,$height], center = true);
}

module nice_cylinder()
{
    translate([0,0,$height/2]) cylinder(d=10,h=$height, center = true);
}

module nice_text()
{
    linear_extrude(height=$height, center=false) text(str($height), size=5);
}

module nice_grid()
{
    for(i=[0:9], j=[0:9])
    {
        $height=(i+1)*(j+1);
        x=10*i;
        y=10*j;
        translate([x,y,0]) children();
        /* let($height=(i+1)*(j+1)) {children();} */
    }
}

nice_grid() nice_cube();
translate([0,-110,0]) nice_grid() nice_text();
translate([-110,0,0]) nice_grid() nice_cylinder();
```

The trick here is to control the shape produced by module by special variables (starting with $) those can be used like in example, commented line using let() requires development version of openscad.

Answer (score 0):

I guess You want this:

```
for(x=[...], y=[...]) {
    translate([x,y,0]) children();
}
```

Note, that you need only one for statement to loop through both x and y values.

What I have understood from your comment is, that you want your objects in the nodes of the grids to be parametric, and parameter depends on index. This requirement was not mentioned in the original question. In this case, solution depends on your problem context, I guess. The two possibilities I see are:

```
module grid_of_parametric_modules(other_param)
{
    for(i=[0:24])
    {
        x=_x(i);
        y=_y(i);
        translate([x,y,0]) parametric_module(i_param(i), other_param);
    }
}
```

However this may not be suitable, especially if You are going to add new shapes to your grid in future. Then you can probably do it like:

```
function grid_pos(i) = [_x(i), _y(i), 0];

....

for(i=[0:24])
    translate(grid_pos(i)) parametric_module(i);
```

Comment: though this is true it should have been a comment (suggesting a better way to write my module grid) because it does not answer my actual Q about generating many cubes and then manipulating them individually and the problems that are introduced by the group added by the 'for' operator.

Comment: It is the answer to your question. If you remove parameter from children(), then you will need to put only one child and it will be placed in grid nodes. Sorry for making the answer too brief, but I hoped you will note that there is no any parameter passed to children() in my code, and that makes a big difference().